# React app not displaying updated array of items

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app to make a D&D character sheet. The languages section takes in race and class as props and updates the languages the character speaks accordingly. The problem happens when the user is prompted to select additional languages from a dropdown menu. Logging the array of languages to the console shows that the user selection from the dropdown menu has been pushed to the array of languages, but the display of languages remains the same. For instance, if the character speaks Common and Gnomish and then selects Giant from the dropdown menu the display only shows Common and Gnomish, even though the array contains Giant as well.

App.js

```
import Languages from './Languages'

return (
//Other stuff
<Languages race={race} characterClass={characterClass} background={background} />
//Other stuff
)
```

Languages.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

function Languages(props) {
let languages = ['Common']
//Other stuff that correctly sets and displays languages according to the race and    background props passed in
const handleLanguage = (e) => {
  languages.push(e.target.value)
}
const displayLangMenu = (propRace, propBack) => {
  (if propRace === 'something' || propBack === 'something else'){
    return (
    <div>
    <p>Please select an additional language from the menu</p>
    <Form.Select onChange={handleLanguage}>
      <option value='some language'>Some language</option>
    </Form.Select>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
console.log(languages)
return (
  <div>
    <Form.Group>
      <h4>Languages</h4>
      {displayLangMenu(props.race, props.background)}
      {languages}
    </Form.Group>
  </div>
)
}
export default Languages
```

I have tried adding a useEffect hook to Languages.js to no avail.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `Languages: ${languages}`
}, [languages])

return (
  <div>
    <Form.Group>
      <h4>Languages: {languages}</h4>
      {displayLangMenu(props.race, props.background}
    </Form.Group>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the updated array is not shown after new items have been pushed because you defined `languages` as a normal variable. For a component to re-render, a **state**  must change its value. Therefore, try assigning your `languages` array as a state using `useState` and update it's value using the setter function; like so:

```js
[languages, setLanguages] = useState(["Common"])
...
...
const handleLanguage = (e) => {
  setLanguages(old => [...old, e.target.value];
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that to Languages.js and got an error saying "Too many rerenders". I tried moving handleLanguage and [languages, setLanguages] = useState(['Common']) to App.js and passing them into Languages.js as props. That got rid of the "too many rerenders" error message, but the app displayed only "Common" as the language, then froze up and became unresponsive. Should I add the useEffect hook back in (I deleted it after it failed to do what I wanted)?